# Android NDK undefined reference to google protobuf

Tags: android, android-studio, c++11, android-ndk, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to make a shared library that uses protobuf-lite with a native library. I've searched around and I can't find anything related to Android Studio 3, google protobuf-lite, and the Android NDK while using windows. I know someone else has had to have tried to do the same thing I'm doing, but my specifics are not apparent in anything I've read.

I'm running:

- Windows 10 64-bit
- Android Studio 3.0.1
- Android NDK r16
- protobuf-lite version 3.0.0
- And targeting armeabi-v7a

I used a DOCKER file to create the libprotobuf-lite.so I'm using.
DOCKER FILE:

```
  FROM debian:stretch

  ENV ANDROID_NDK_HOME /build/android-ndk
  ENV ANDROID_NDK_VERSION=r16

  RUN set -e -x && \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y \
    unzip \
    wget

  #ADD android-ndk-${ANDROID_NDK_VERSION}-linux-x86_32.zip /build/android-
   ndk.zip
  RUN set -e -x && \
  mkdir /build && \
  cd /build && \
  wget -q https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-
  ndk-${ANDROID_NDK_VERSION}-linux-x86_32.zip -O android-ndk.zip && \
  unzip -q android-ndk.zip && \
  mv ./android-ndk-${ANDROID_NDK_VERSION} ${ANDROID_NDK_HOME} && \
  rm android-ndk.zip

  #ADD protobuf-cpp-3.0.0.zip /build/protobuf.zip
  RUN set -e -x && \
  cd /build && \
  wget -q 
  https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/download/v3.0.0/protobuf-cpp-
  3.0.0.zip -O protobuf-src.zip && \
  unzip protobuf-src.zip && \
  mv protobuf-3.0.0 protobuf && \
  rm protobuf-src.zip

  RUN set -e -x && \
  cd /build && \
  wget -q 
  https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/download/v3.0.0/protoc-3.0.0-
  linux-x86_32.zip -O protoc.zip && \
  mkdir protoc && \
  cd protoc && \
  unzip ../protoc.zip && \
  cd .. && \
  rm protoc.zip

  RUN set -e -x && \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y \
    # protobuf compile
    autoconf \
    automake \
    libtool \
    curl \
    make \
    g++ \
    # additional compile not in readme
    libncurses5-dev \
    # make_standalone_toolchain
    python \
    # util
    nano

  RUN /build/android-ndk/build/tools/make_standalone_toolchain.py \
     --arch arm \
     --install-dir /build/android-arm

  ADD build.sh /build
  WORKDIR /build/protobuf


  CMD /bin/bash
```

I am writing a c++ library to be able to use from the java side. I have an Android.mk file that I'm using in Android Studio to build the native library.

Android.mk File:

```
    LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

    include $(CLEAR_VARS)
    LOCAL_MODULE := protobuf-lite
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libprotobuf-lite.so
    LOCAL_CFLAGS    := -std=c++11
    include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

    include $(CLEAR_VARS)
    LOCAL_MODULE := native-lib
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := native-lib.cpp \
        BeaconSearchResult.cpp \
        fileformat.pb.cc \
        Geopoint.cpp \
        Location.cpp \
        osmformat.pb.cc \
        osmpbf.cpp \
        OSMPBFread.cpp \
        OSMPOISearch.cpp \
        POI.cpp \
   TARGET_ARCH_ABI := armeabi-v7a
   LOCAL_LDFLAGS := -lz -llog
   LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libprotobuf-lite
   LOCAL_CPP_FEATURES := rtti
   LOCAL_CFLAGS    := -std=c++11
   include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

The errors I get are:

```
  Error:(511) undefined reference to 'google::protobuf::internal::MergeFromFail(char const*, int)'
  Error:(521) undefined reference to 'google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::AssignWithDefault(std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char> > const*, google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr)'
  Error:(237) undefined reference to 'google::protobuf::io::LazyStringOutputStream::LazyStringOutputStream(google::protobuf::ResultCallback<std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char> >*>*)'
  Error:(377) undefined reference to 'google::protobuf::io::LazyStringOutputStream::~LazyStringOutputStream()'
  Error:(390) undefined reference to 'google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::WriteString(int, std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::all
  Error:(817) undefined reference to 'google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream::VarintSize64(unsigned long long)'
  Error:(830) undefined reference to 'google::protobuf::Arena::AddListNode(void*, void (*)(void*))'
  Error:(640) undefined reference to 'google::protobuf::Arena::AllocateAligned(std::type_info const*, unsigned int)'
```

And those errors appear in the files:

- osmformat.pb.cc
- protobuf/wire_format_lite_inl.h
- protobuf/arena.h
- protobuf/generated_message_util.h
- and fileformat.pb.cc

In total there are 49 errors. I know something I'm doing must be correct because if I take out the line in the Android.mk that is LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES it gives me 159 errors. I'm at my wit's end and I could really use some fresh eyes on this. If you need any more information let me know.

Edit: I found some more error information in the gradle console:

```
  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

  * What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:externalNativeBuildDebug'.
  > Build command failed.
  Error while executing process C:\Users\jkarr\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\Users\jkarr\Hellocmake\app\src\main\jni\armeabi-v7a\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=C:\Users\jkarr\Hellocmake\app\src\main\jni\armeabi-v7a\Application.mk APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi-v7a NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-15 NDK_OUT=C:/Users/jkarr/Hellocmake/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\Users\jkarr\Hellocmake\app\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\debug\lib C:/Users/jkarr/Hellocmake/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libnative-lib.so}
  Android NDK: WARNING: Unsupported source file extensions in C:\Users\jkarr\Hellocmake\app\src\main\jni\armeabi-v7a\Android.mk for module native-lib    
  Android NDK:   TARGET_ARCH_ABI := armeabi-v7a 
  [armeabi-v7a] SharedLibrary  : libnative-lib.so
  C:/Users/jkarr/Hellocmake/app/src/main/jni/armeabi-v7a/osmformat.pb.cc:512: error: undefined reference to 'google::protobuf::internal::MergeFromFail(char const*, int)'
  C:/Users/jkarr/Hellocmake/app/src/main/jni/armeabi-v7a/osmformat.pb.cc:522: error: undefined reference to 'google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::AssignWithDefault(std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char> > const*, google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr)'
  C:/Users/jkarr/Hellocmake/app/src/main/jni/armeabi-v7a/osmformat.pb.cc:526: error: undefined reference to 'google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::AssignWithDefault(std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char> > const*, google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr)'
  C:/Users/jkarr/Hellocmake/app/src/main/jni/armeabi-v7a/osmformat.pb.cc:536: error: undefined reference to 'google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::AssignWithDefault(std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char> > const*, google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr)'
  C:/Users/jkarr/Hellocmake/app/src/main/jni/armeabi-v7a/google/include/protobuf/arena.h:830: error: undefined reference to 'google::protobuf::Arena::AddListNode(void*, void (*)(void*))'
  C:/Users/jkarr/Hellocmake/app/src/main/jni/armeabi-v7a/osmformat.pb.cc:238: error: undefined reference to 'google::protobuf::io::LazyStringOutputStream::LazyStringOutputStream(google::protobuf::ResultCallback<std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char> >*>*)'
  C:/Users/jkarr/Hellocmake/app/src/main/jni/armeabi-v7a/osmformat.pb.cc:378: error: undefined reference to 'google::protobuf::io::LazyStringOutputStream::~LazyStringOutputStream()'
  C:/Users/jkarr/Hellocmake/app/src/main/jni/armeabi-v7a/osmformat.pb.cc:391: error: undefined reference to 'google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::WriteString(int, std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char> > const&, google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream*)'
  C:/Users/jkarr/Hellocmake/app/src/main/jni/armeabi-v7a/osmformat.pb.cc:397: error: undefined reference to 'google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::WriteString(int, std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char> > const&, google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream*)'
  C:/Users/jkarr/Hellocmake/app/src/main/jni/armeabi-v7a/osmformat.pb.cc:403: error: undefined reference to 'google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::WriteStringMaybeAliased(int, std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char> > const&, google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream*)'
  C:/Users/jkarr/Hellocmake/app/src/main/jni/armeabi-v7a/osmformat.pb.cc:409: error: undefined reference to 'google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::WriteStringMaybeAliased(int, std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char> > const&, google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream*)'
  C:/Users/jkarr/Hellocmake/app/src/main/jni/armeabi-v7a/osmformat.pb.cc:425: error: undefined reference to 'google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::WriteStringMaybeAliased(int, std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char> > const&, google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream*)'
  C:/Users/jkarr/Hellocmake/app/src/main/jni/armeabi-v7a/google/include/protobuf/wire_format_lite_inl.h:817: error: undefined reference to 'google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream::VarintSize64(unsigned long long)'
  C:/Users/jkarr/Hellocmake/app/src/main/jni/armeabi-v7a/osmformat.pb.cc:1267: error: undefined reference to 'google::protobuf::internal::MergeFromFail(char const*, int)'
  C:/Users/jkarr/Hellocmake/app/src/main/jni/armeabi-v7a/google/include/protobuf/arena.h:830: error: undefined reference to 'google::protobuf::Arena::AddListNode(void*, void (*)(void*))'
  C:/Users/jkarr/Hellocmake/app/src/main/jni/armeabi-v7a/osmformat.pb.cc:1069: error: undefined reference to 'google::protobuf::io::LazyStringOutputStream::LazyStringOutputStream(google::protobuf::ResultCallback<std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char> >*>*)'
  C:/Users/jkarr/Hellocmake/app/src/main/jni/armeabi-v7a/osmformat.pb.cc:1159: error: undefined reference to 'google::protobuf::io::LazyStringOutputStream::~LazyStringOutputStream()'
  C:/Users/jkarr/Hellocmake/app/src/main/jni/armeabi-v7a/google/include/protobuf/wire_format_lite_inl.h:829: error: undefined reference to 'google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream::VarintSize64(unsigned long long)'
  C:/Users/jkarr/Hellocmake/app/src/main/jni/armeabi-v7a/osmformat.pb.cc:1760: error: undefined reference to 'google::protobuf::internal::MergeFromFail(char const*, int)'
  C:/Users/jkarr/Hellocmake/app/src/main/jni/armeabi-v7a/google/include/protobuf/arena.h:830: error: undefined reference to 'google::protobuf::Arena::AddListNode(void*, void (*)(void*))'
  C:/Users/jkarr/Hellocmake/app/src/main/jni/armeabi-v7a/osmformat.pb.cc:1534: error: undefined reference to 'google::protobuf::io::LazyStringOutputStream::LazyStringOutputStream(google::protobuf::ResultCallback<std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char> >*>*)'
  C:/Users/jkarr/Hellocmake/app/src/main/jni/armeabi-v7a/osmformat.pb.cc:1654: error: undefined reference to 'google::protobuf::io::LazyStringOutputStream::~LazyStringOutputStream()'
  C:/Users/jkarr/Hellocmake/app/src/main/jni/armeabi-v7a/osmformat.pb.cc:2712: error: undefined reference to 'google::protobuf::internal::MergeFromFail(char const*, int)'
  C:/Users/jkarr/Hellocmake/app/src/main/jni/armeabi-v7a/google/include/protobuf/arena.h:830: error: undefined reference to 'google::protobuf::Arena::AddListNode(void*, void (*)(void*))'
  C:/Users/jkarr/Hellocmake/app/src/main/jni/armeabi-v7a/osmformat.pb.cc:2104: error: undefined reference to 'google::protobuf::io::LazyStringOutputStream::LazyStringOutputStream(google::protobuf::ResultCallback<std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char> >*>*)'
  C:/Users/jkarr/Hellocmake/app/src/main/jni/armeabi-v7a/osmformat.pb.cc:2213: error: undefined reference to 'google::protobuf::io::LazyStringOutputStream::~LazyStringOutputStream()'
  C:/Users/jkarr/Hellocmake/app/src/main/jni/armeabi-v7a/osmformat.pb.cc:2639: error: undefined reference to 'google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::ReadBytes(google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream*, std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char> >*)'
  C:/Users/jkarr/Hellocmake/app/src/main/jni/armeabi-v7a/osmformat.pb.cc:2676: error: undefined reference to 'google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::WriteBytes(int, std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char> > const&, google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream*)'
  C:/Users/jkarr/Hellocmake/app/src/main/jni/armeabi-v7a/google/include/protobuf/wire_format_lite_inl.h:544: error: undefined reference to 'google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream::WriteVarint64(unsigned long long)'
  C:/Users/jkarr/Hellocmake/app/src/main/jni/armeabi-v7a/google/include/protobuf/wire_format_lite_inl.h:544: error: undefined reference to 'google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream::WriteVarint64(unsigned long long)'
  C:/Users/jkarr/Hellocmake/app/src/main/jni/armeabi-v7a/google/include/protobuf/wire_format_lite_inl.h:544: error: undefined reference to 'google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream::WriteVarint64(unsigned long long)'
  C:/Users/jkarr/Hellocmake/app/src/main/jni/armeabi-v7a/google/include/protobuf/wire_format_lite_inl.h:544: error: undefined reference to 'google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream::WriteVarint64(unsigned long long)'
  C:/Users/jkarr/Hellocmake/app/src/main/jni/armeabi-v7a/google/include/protobuf/arena.h:640: error: undefined reference to 'google::protobuf::Arena::AllocateAligned(std::type_info const*, unsigned int)'
  C:/Users/jkarr/Hellocmake/app/src/main/jni/armeabi-v7a/google/include/protobuf/arena.h:640: error: undefined reference to 'google::protobuf::Arena::AllocateAligned(std::type_info const*, unsigned int)'
  C:/Users/jkarr/Hellocmake/app/src/main/jni/armeabi-v7a/google/include/protobuf/arena.h:640: error: undefined reference to 'google::protobuf::Arena::AllocateAligned(std::type_info const*, unsigned int)'
  C:/Users/jkarr/Hellocmake/app/src/main/jni/armeabi-v7a/google/include/protobuf/arena.h:640: error: undefined reference to 'google::protobuf::Arena::AllocateAligned(std::type_info const*, unsigned int)'
  C:/Users/jkarr/Hellocmake/app/src/main/jni/armeabi-v7a/fileformat.pb.cc:372: error: undefined reference to 'google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::AssignWithDefault(std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char> > const*, google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr)'
  C:/Users/jkarr/Hellocmake/app/src/main/jni/armeabi-v7a/google/include/protobuf/generated_message_util.h:87: error: undefined reference to 'google::protobuf::internal::empty_string_'
  C:/Users/jkarr/Hellocmake/app/src/main/jni/armeabi-v7a/google/include/protobuf/generated_message_util.h:87: error: undefined reference to 'google::protobuf::internal::empty_string_'
  C:/Users/jkarr/Hellocmake/app/src/main/jni/armeabi-v7a/fileformat.pb.cc:188: error: undefined reference to 'google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::ReadBytes(google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream*, std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char> >*)'
  C:/Users/jkarr/Hellocmake/app/src/main/jni/armeabi-v7a/fileformat.pb.cc:216: error: undefined reference to 'google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::ReadBytes(google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream*, std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char> >*)'
  C:/Users/jkarr/Hellocmake/app/src/main/jni/armeabi-v7a/fileformat.pb.cc:229: error: undefined reference to 'google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::ReadBytes(google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream*, std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char> >*)'
  C:/Users/jkarr/Hellocmake/app/src/main/jni/armeabi-v7a/fileformat.pb.cc:278: error: undefined reference to 'google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::WriteBytesMaybeAliased(int, std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char> > const&, google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream*)'
  C:/Users/jkarr/Hellocmake/app/src/main/jni/armeabi-v7a/fileformat.pb.cc:289: error: undefined reference to 'google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::WriteBytesMaybeAliased(int, std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char> > const&, google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream*)'
  C:/Users/jkarr/Hellocmake/app/src/main/jni/armeabi-v7a/fileformat.pb.cc:295: error: undefined reference to 'google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::WriteBytesMaybeAliased(int, std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char> > const&, google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream*)'
  C:/Users/jkarr/Hellocmake/app/src/main/jni/armeabi-v7a/fileformat.pb.cc:301: error: undefined reference to 'google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::WriteBytesMaybeAliased(int, std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char> > const&, google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream*)'
  C:/Users/jkarr/Hellocmake/app/src/main/jni/armeabi-v7a/fileformat.pb.cc:852: error: undefined reference to 'google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::WriteStringMaybeAliased(int, std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char> > const&, google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream*)'
  C:/Users/jkarr/Hellocmake/app/src/main/jni/armeabi-v7a/google/include/protobuf/io/coded_stream.h:1232: error: undefined reference to 'google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream::VarintSize32Fallback(unsigned int)'
  clang++.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
  make: ***[C:/Users/jkarr/Hellocmake/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libnative-lib.so] Error 1


  * Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

  * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

  BUILD FAILED in 2s
```

Comment: Don't try to override `TARGET_ARCH_ABI` in **Android.mk**, you can set `APP_ABI` when you build on command line, or `abiFilters` in **build.gradle**.

Comment: Ok, I'm still new to this. I actually do have the abiFilter in my build.gradle. I go ahead and change that then.  EDIT: There was no change. Thanks for pointing that out though. In the future, I won't try to override the target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that the things causing undefined reference errors were undefined in the .h files. I was under the impression that I would only need the .h files to use the protobuf library, but I need the accompanying .cc files to have the said functions be defined. I appreciate everyone who tried to help. Hopefully, my experience will be used to help someone else.